# Do I have to pre-compile asp.net mvc apps?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In WebForms we can leave the compilation until the first request in IIS. It is then compiled and requests are served.

In ASP.NET MVC can I do the same thing, or do I have to pre-compile the app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to pre-compile if you don't want to. ASP.NET MVC is only a wrapper around existing ASP.NET structures.

Comment: Thank you. Now that I know I can do it, I'll continue trying to actually get it to work.

Comment: Make sure the dll's are in your bin directory fyi.

Comment: The MVC dll's are in the GAC.

Comment: Also, the trick to doing this is that you have to put your Controller and Model code in the App_Code folder so that it is compiled on first request.

Answer (score 1):

It is upto you whether you want to use the [precompilation tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863(VS.80).aspx) or not to speed up the first request. Does not matter whether the app is Webforms or MVC.